# save listview data in mysql query browser database

Tags: mysql, vb.net, mysql-connector

```
    Dim lvitem As Object
    Dim iCount As Integer
    Dim iLoop As Integer
    Dim query3 = New SqlCommand
    query3.Connection = New SqlConnection("SERVER=localhost;UID=root;DATABASE=test;")
    iCount = lvLogs.Items.Count()
    If Not lvLogs.Items.Count = 0 Then
        Do Until iLoop = lvLogs.Items.Count
            lvitem = lvLogs.Items.Item(iLoop)
            With LvItem
                query3.CommandText = "insert into wer(CustomerName,SalesGroup,CustomerType,TypeOfIndustry,RM,SeniorRM) values('" & .SubItems(0).Text & "','" & .SubItems(1).Text & "','" & .SubItems(2).Text & "','" & .SubItems(3).Text & "','" & .SubItems(4).Text & "','" & .SubItems(5).Text & "')"
                query3.ExecuteNonQuery()
            End With
            iLoop = iLoop + 1
            LvItem = Nothing
        Loop
    End If
    MessageBox.Show("Record Saved!")
```

That is my code. message box show up but the record is not saved in my database. please help me

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `SqlClient` provider. You must have to use [MySql .net](http://www.mysql.com/products/connector/) connector API and take a look at [MySql connector examples](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/es/connector-net-examples.html).

Comment: where can i find it? what should i click?

Comment: @SigridAnnOmila - Click on the links I've pasted in my post.